# Outlook email performance slow using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Outlook sends emails really slowly.

Moreover my CPU is at 15-20% and my 16G ram is at 50% utilization...so this could be either an issue of code performance or of resource allocation.

I have included my code below:

```
 'my code
    Sub SendMail(what_address As String, subject_line As String, mail_body As String)

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With olMail
            .To = what_address
            .Subject = subject_line
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\User\Documents\Association\Event Brochure\BROCHURE.pdf"
            .HTMLBody = mail_body
            .Send
        End With

    End Sub 'Tells outlook to send an input, with an attachment I selected


    Sub SendMassMail()

    row_number = 1

    Do
    DoEvents
        row_number = row_number + 1
        Dim mail_body_message As String
        Dim name As String
        Dim mrmrs As String
        Dim company_name As String

        mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("I2")
        name = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number)
        mrmrs = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number)
        company_name = Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)

        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_mrmrs_here", mrmrs)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", name)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_company_here", company_name)


        Call SendMail(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number), "Event Sponsorship", mail_body_message)

    Loop Until row_number = 500

    End Sub
```

This code is two macros I created in Excel sheet which contains the email addresses in Column A, Names in Column B, Mr/Mrs in Column C, the company in Column D, and finally the message body in cell I2, which has key words to be replaced for each recipient.

Now regarding the resource allocation. In task manager I gave both excel.exe and Outlook.exe a high priority.

Is my code running badly because I call another function when I use Call SendMail?

Is my code running badly because I use DoEvent? That is the only method I know...so if you suggest a different one than DoEvent please explain what it does.

Comment: This code really looks good to me. The only thing I can see that *possibly maybe* might help is to change the flow: 1) Create the outlook object 2)loop your records and send the email 3) end the routine (destroying your 1 outlook object). This way you aren't constantly creating an instance of the outlook object for all items in your loop.

Comment: All DoEvents does is surrender control to the operating system. You would use it if you wanted a userform to continually refresh while some code is running. Another note (and this isn't on the code aspect), but I'd say it's almost always a bad idea to send emails to people outside your organization completely automatically. Usually you'd want to have the code save your emails as a draft, then manually click send in Outlook. If you have a bug in your code, you really don't want to accidentally send hundreds of spam emails to the people you're looking to get money from.

Comment: @JNevill I understand the idea of what you're trying to say...but I'm not skilled enough to know how to code that. Can I please ask you for a demonstration/example?

Comment: *Is my code running badly because I use DoEvent?*
Please comment that line and try without it.

Comment: Question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick rewrite where I've:

1. Put all the code into a single routine. We create the outlook application once and send many times from the one instance
2. Switched to a For Each loop which is a little cleaner
3. Removed the `DoEvents` into a comment. ***IF*** you absolute need to be able to break code execution while it's running then you'll want to keep `DoEvents` in your loop. If you don't care though and just want the thing to run as fast as possible, then leave it out. I would suggest (as @JoshEller noted) that saving these emails as drafts first might be the better alternative. Then you can send manually from your outlook catching any mistakes that may have been made before it's too late (and embarrassing).

```
Sub SendMassMail()  
    'Create your outlook object once:
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Declare your mail object
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    'Some variables used in the loop. Declare outside:
    Dim mail_body_message As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim mrmrs As String
    Dim company_name As String

    'Do your loop. Using a for loop here so we don't need a counter
    Dim rngRow as Range
    For each rngRow in Sheet1.Range("B2:B500").Rows
        'No reason to do this here
        'DoEvents

        mail_body_message = Sheet1.Range("I2")
        name = rngRow.Cells(1, 2).value 'Column B
        mrmrs = rngRow.Cells(1, 3).Value 'Column C
        company_name = rngRow.Cells(1, 4).value 'Column D

        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_mrmrs_here", mrmrs)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", name)
        mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_company_here", company_name)

        'Generate the email and send
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

        With olMail
            .To = rngRow.Cells(1,1).value 'Column A
            .Subject = "M&A Forum Event Sponseorship"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\User\Documents\Association\Event Brochure\BROCHURE.pdf"
            .HTMLBody = mail_body_message
            .Send

            'Instead of .send, consider using:
            '.Save
            '.Close
            'Then you'll have it as a draft and you can send from outlook directly
        End With        

    Next rngRow

    'Destroy the outlook application
    Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The comments in your code made it really clear to understand. For the last step when you say "destroy the outlook application" my understanding is that this is the equivalent to pressing X to close the window? Since we closed the loop, what happens if I don't destroy the application? This is just for my understanding of the theory.

Comment: It really doesn't matter. You can omit that line completely and VBA will destroy the application when the subroutine ends. I like to have it in there though since I may come back to this code in 6 months and add some more logic to the end of it... no reason to keep the application around if it isn't needed. And yes, you can think of that as hitting the `x` button to close.

Comment: Thanks Again! Really appreciate you took the time to help